# How to make city as Dropdown in checkout pages

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to make city as dropdown in checkout page in magento 2.

I also used below module 
https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

But this one only working for Romania not for other country.

If someone can help in This

Advanced Thanks

Comment: You need to import cities list first to make it work for other countries.

Comment: i have but i am not able to show on frontend

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide the steps you followed to add cities, so someone can check and resolve your issue or suggest what you are doing wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown
This module i am using which add a separate table for city its working fine for country Romania but not for other country

Comment: I meant, please add the steps for how you added your cities using the module. As per module, it provides cities for Romania. for which country did you try to add cities and how.?

Comment: i upload city for like United states with states(region id =12) and add some cities to that region but city not showing for that region.

Comment: Do you have any idea if i have collection of city that is store in database. how to show when user select any particular state of country.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaimin says, you have to import cities list. There is also another way of doing it very easily with the [Aitoc Checkout Fields](https://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_checkoutfieldsmanager.html) plugin. It allows you to add new checkout fields, like city in dropdown, without using the module. So, it can save a lot of your time.

Comment: i don't want to used paid module. Any other Suggestion please

Comment: stay far away from the AITOC module - functionality is great, but they have lost whoever used to be their good developers. The Magento 1 module is not compatible with Braintree or Stripe and not compatible with 1.9.4 and nothing has been done in 6 months. I wouldnt trust the M2 one either.